# Inherited __init__() function not working as intended

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I was working on a game using the `pygame` library on Python. I basically defined a `Character` class from which the `Knight` class and `Enemy` class would inherit functions. Since both children classes use the same initialize functions, I defined the `__init__()` function under the parent class. However, I don't fully understand how it works and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Here's my code:

```
class Character():

    def __init__(self, img, hitbox, vel, pos_x, pos_y):
        self.img = img
        self.hitbox = hitbox
        self.vel = vel
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
    
    def draw(self):
        
        if self.right:
            pygame.transform.flip(self.img, True, False)
        
        win.blit(self.img, (self.pos_x, self.pos_y))

class Knight(Character):
    
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self)

    def move(self):
        if self.right:
            if self.x + self.vel < win_width:
                self.x += self.vel
        if self.left:
            if self.x - self.vel > 0:
                self.x -= self.vel

main_plr = Knight("img", (19, 20), 5, 30, 20)
```

Comment: You may as well just delete the `__init__` out of the knight class since it doesnt do any of its own initializing

Comment: Read https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on how to define `__init__` in a way that avoids repetition and plays well with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a quick fix: just remove the `__init__` method from `Knight`.

The error is raised because you create a `Knight` object with 6
arguments (`self, "img", (19, 20), 5, 30, 20`) whereas the `__init__` method accepts only one (`self`).

So if your `Knight` objects do not have any additional attributes
compared to `Character` objects, it will be just fine to remove the
`__init__` method.  Now if you want your knight to have weapons, for
example, you will have to do something like that:

```py
class Knight(Character):

   def __init__(self, img, hitbox, vel, pos_x, pos_y, weapon):
      super().__init__(img, hitbox, vel, pos_x, pos_y)
      self.weapon = weapon

k = Knight("img", (19, 20), 5, 30, 20, "sword")
```

**[Edit]**

Additionaly, as suggested by @Matiiss, you can use `*args` to avoid
repeating all arguments of `Character.__init__` in `Knight.__init__`.
One advantage, besides conciseness, is that you do not have to modify
`Knight` if you add attributes to your `Character` objects.

```py
class Knight(Character):

    def __init__(self, *args, weapon):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.weapon = weapon

k = Knight("img", (19, 20), 5, 30, 20, weapon="sword")
```

But now the drawback is that you have to specify the `weapon` with
`weapon="the-weapon"`, since it is now a keyword argument (placed
after `*args`).

Comment: additionally for shortening the code you could use `def __init__(self, *args, weapon)` and then `super().__init__(*args)`, but then it would have to be instantiated like this: `k = Knight('img', (19, 20), 5, 30, 20, weapon='sword')`

Comment: @Matiiss Many thanks for the suggestion.  I included it in my answer.

Comment: oh, actually you can do it like this: `def __init__(self, *args):` then `super().__init__(args[:-1])` (or `args[:5]` which may be better) and then `self.weapon = args[-1]` (or `args[5]`), then it would be a positional argument (although not as explicit as what is should be (basically possible but explicitness is better so wouldn't really suggest using it))

Comment: @Matiiss `args[:5]` and `args[5]` are bad IMHO because then you lose one major advantage which is that you can modify `Character.__init__` signature without having to modify `Knight.__init__`.

Comment: yes, that and also that it may be harder to understand what the argument represents

Answer (score 2):

As the error you are seeing says, your `Knight` constructor does not accept those arguments; if you are going to use that kind of inherited method extension, the class and subclass methods need to have matching argument signatures. It's also best to use `super()` to refer to the superclass rather than naming it explicitly.

The simplest way of handling this is to use `*args` and `**kwargs`, to concisely pass arguments that aren't needed by the subclass method to the superclass method, ie

```
class Character():

    def __init__(self, img, hitbox, vel, pos_x, pos_y):
        self.img = img
        self.hitbox = hitbox
        self.vel = vel
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
    

class Knight(Character):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def move(self):
        if self.right:
            if self.x + self.vel < win_width:
                self.x += self.vel
        if self.left:
            if self.x - self.vel > 0:
                self.x -= self.vel
```